# How can I get the column value from the most recent date?

Tags: sap-ase

Running this on Sybase ASE.
I get an error Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is illegal when the subquery follow =, etc.

In the subquery I'm trying to select the latest value by date.

Data would be something like
Doc_no user Date
AA    jones 23 Mar 2018
AA    steph 10 Mar 2018
BB    dan   1 Jan 2018
BB    jon   1 Jan 2010

In this example, I should get 2 values returned to join on and display.
AA should show jones
BB should show dan since they have the latest date.
The data is actually millions of rows to search through.

```
use mydb_hist
go
select
d.doc_no,
d.doc_short_name,
d.doc_name,
r.doc_no,
r.revision_code,
r.revision,
r.description,
d.last_update,
d.document_category_code,
d.business_group_code,
(case
when substring(grp.group_name,1,10) = 'GEL IPP Do' THEN 'Yes'
else 'No'
END) as 'GEL',
(SELECT d2.index_user_id
       FROM   document_instance d2
        WHERE  d2.doc_no     = d1.doc_no
        and    d2.entry_time = (select max(d3.entry_time)
                                from   document_instance d3
                                where  d3.doc_no = d1.doc_no)
       ) as 'last indexed by'
from documents d
join document_revision r on r.doc_no = d.doc_no
left join mydb..document_type_group grp on grp.doc_no = d.doc_no and substring(grp.group_name,1,10) = 'Leg PII Do'
left join mydb..document_instance d1 on d1.doc_no = d.doc_no
where d.dbOprnCD = 'I'
and d.last_update > '1 Jan 2018'

--and grp.group_name LIKE 'GEL%' --shortened this so the substring in the group by matches, getting a server error for the work table size otherwise

group by d.doc_no,
d.doc_short_name,
d.doc_name,
r.doc_no,
r.revision_code,
r.revision,
r.description,
d.last_update,
d.document_category_code,
d.business_group_code,
substring(grp.group_name,1,10)
```

Comment: What is the primary key for document_instance table?  If the combination of entry_time  and doc_no are not unique in d2, then you could get multiple index_user_id records.  Also, did you try running the sub-select raw to see what the duplicate values are?  Identifying the exact data that is causing the problem would help solve this.

Comment: the primary key is called uid. I could select that but I cannot put top 1 or order by in the subquery. I fiugured out the multiple rows issue as I needed to specify the database but now I cannot group by that subquery

Comment: if I do group by d2.index_user_id it does not recognize the alias

Answer (score 0):

How about this?
If index_user_id is not unique for a given doc_no and entry_date then you need to move the subselect to the join below.  This will then allow you to include index_user_id in the group by clause.

```
use mydb_hist
go
select
d.doc_no,
d.doc_short_name,
d.doc_name,
r.doc_no,
r.revision_code,
r.revision,
r.description,
d.last_update,
d.document_category_code,
d.business_group_code,
(case
when substring(grp.group_name,1,10) = 'GEL IPP Do' THEN 'Yes'
else 'No'
END) as 'GEL',
d1.index_user_id as 'last indexed by'
from documents d
join document_revision r on r.doc_no = d.doc_no
left join mydb..document_type_group grp on grp.doc_no = d.doc_no and substring(grp.group_name,1,10) = 'Leg PII Do'
left join mydb..document_instance d1 on d1.doc_no = d.doc_no and d1.entry_time = (select max(d3.entry_time)
                                                                                  from   mydb..document_instance d3
                                                                                  where  d3.doc_no = d1.doc_no)
where d.dbOprnCD = 'I'
and d.last_update > '1 Jan 2018'
group by d.doc_no,
d.doc_short_name,
d.doc_name,
r.doc_no,
r.revision_code,
r.revision,
r.description,
d.last_update,
d.document_category_code,
d.business_group_code,
substring(grp.group_name,1,10)
d1.index_user_id
```